# Where to find Endpoint in creating aws-cli bots without using amazon-lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bots, aws-cli, chatbot, amazon-lex

I'm trying to create a chatbot using aws-cli .Going through the Steps in Documentation in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-create-flower-types.html
I couldn't understand what endpoint did it mean in the documentation as shown in the syntax.

```
  aws lex-models put-slot-type \
    --region region \
    --endpoint endpoint \
    --name FlowerTypes \
    --cli-input-json file://FlowerTypes.json
```

What is the endpoint in the above syntax?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the list of endpoints for Lex at this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#lex_region)

For your current case, https://models.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ will work as endpoint, given that your region is **us-east-1**.

[image: Endpoints Lex Screenshot]

Below code will work if you are using Windows machine:

```
aws lex-models put-slot-type ^
    --region us-east-1 ^
    --endpoint https://models.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ ^
    --name FlowerTypes ^
    --cli-input-json file://FlowerTypes.json
```

Keep the input json file in the same folder where you have opened the CLI.